# How to get a list from a Pandas' series which includes the index of the row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` (created from an excel file) in which I want to look into a row, ignore `nan` values, and get the position of the remaining elements. So I'm doing:

```
lines = df.iloc[16, :].dropna()
print(lines)
```

Which yields:

```
2      10
6      11
10     12
14     13
18     14
```

Where the first column is the automatic indexing that Pandas gives to each row in my excel. I want a list those index, `position = [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]`.

How can I extract those indices? I tried with `lines.tolist()` but it only gets the values without the position/index.

Comment: `lines.index.tolist()`

Comment: `df.iloc[16, :].dropna().index.tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following line:

```
lines.index.tolist()
```

Alternatively `list(lines.index)` would also work